# Tanimoto coefficient distance measure

Tags: math, distance, trigonometry

Can two objects have identical cosine and Tanimoto coefficient distance measure, where

```
Tanimoto distance measure, d(x,y) = x.y / (|x|*|x|) + (|y|*|y|)- x*y
```

and

```
cosine measure, d(x,y) = x.y /(|x|* |x|) * (|y| *|y|)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Tanimoto similarity coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index#Other_definitions_of_Tanimoto_distance) (which is *not* a true distance measure) is defined
by

```
d(x,y) = x.y / ((|x|*|x|) + (|y|*|y|)- x.y)
```

for bit vectors x and y.

Now compare that with the [cosine similarity coefficent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity),

```
 d(x,y) = x.y / (|x| * |y|)
```

The denominators differ by a `x.y` term. The Tanimoto and cosine similarity coefficients would be the same if `x.y` is zero.

Geometrically, `x.y` is zero if and only if `x` and `y` are perpendicular.

Since `x` and `y` are bit vectors (i.e. whose values in each dimension can only be 0 or 1), `x.y` equalling zero means

```
x1*y1 + x2*y2 + ... + xn*yn = 0
```

If xi*yi = 1*1 = 1, then the whole sum would be positive. For the whole sum to be zero, *no term* xi*yi can equal 1. They must all equal 0:

So

```
x1*y1 = 0
x2*y2 = 0
...
xn*yn = 0
```

In other words, if xi is 1, then yi must be 0, and vice versa.

So there are tons of examples where the Tanimoto similarity is equal to the cosine similarity:

```
x = (0,1,0,1)
y = (1,0,0,0)
```

for instance.

Comment: Isn't the formula for cosine similarity wrong?? the correct formula is "x.y/|x|*|y|"

Comment: @SanketDeshmukh: Oops, you are right. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the general form of Tanimoto distance was presented, you must always remember that, computationally, there is a binary form and continuous form.

The binary form is:

```
d(x,y) = n(X ∩ Y) / [ n(X) + n(Y) - n(X ∩ Y) ]
```

while the continuous form is:

```
d(x,y) = X.Y / (||X|| + ||Y|| - X.Y )
```

The difference is clear.  If a coder is working for you, you must instruct them that n(X ∩ Y), n(X), n(Y) only involves counting the number of ones in the vectors.   Whereas for ||X|| and ||Y|| you must state that the square root of (X1^2 + X2^2 + ... Xp^2) is required since ||X|| is the length of the vector X from the origin (also called the norm).  Taking square roots for the binary form is unnecessary and would be computationally expensive (wasteful) for big data mining, since irrational math functions are expensive.  However, for the continuous variant, you must use the square root.

In summary, always remember that for Tanimoto distance, there are two types: binary and continuous.

Comment: can you give example calculation for Tanimoto continuous form? how X.Y becomes a numeric from vector? ty

Comment: X.Y is the dot product, which is equal to X1*Y1 + X2*Y2 + ... + XP*YP.  The dot product is the sum of many products and is a scalar (single real-valued number). Another notation used in matrix algebra is X^TY or X'Y