# How to compare and identify similarities between customer orders on the same list

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerquery, powerpivot

I'm stuck trying to solve the below excel problem.

I have a list of customer orders that I'm trying to compare with each other to get a percentage total. The percentage should identify the similarities between each order set based on the item type. So for example, the total number of orders under Matt would be compared with the total number of orders under Jennifer and Walter. There should be two seperate percentage totals for each customer. So in the example with Matt the percentage total would identify how similar Matts order is to Jennifer's order and there would be another percentage total that would identify how similar Matts order is to Walter's order.

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem and have been pulling my hair out in the research process to find a solution. I have tried approaching it from a one-to-many/many-to-many relationship but am not sure how it would work with a single list.

[Customer Order List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhkB5.png)

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that 200+ customers,  how many item types ? So for each item type potentially there would be a 200+ x 200+ matrix of results.

Comment: For comparisons like this there are a number of scores you can use - Tanimoto might be useful to try out.  Eg: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558830/tanimoto-score-and-when-it-is-used

Answer (score 1):

I thought this might be an interesting challenge in Power Query to generate the Jaccard-Tanimoto coefficient for the different comparisons.

***Algorithm***

- Group the table by Customer
- Generate a List of the items for each customre
- Using a recursive custom function, generate a List of all possible Combinations given the number of customers.

  - This List contains all possible number combinations using Pairs of numbers where the numbers represent the Index into the unique List of customers.  So for a customer count of 3, we would generate {0,1}{0,2}{1,2}
  - We then use that List of Indexes to generate both our coefficient and the corresponding list of customer comparisons.
  - For the coefficient, I used the formula `Nc/(Na+Nb-Nc)` where `Nc` is the count of the Union of the two lists, and `Na` and `Nb` is the count of each of the two lists.

***Custom Function***
*Enter as a blank query and Rename `fnCombo`*

```
//generate all possible combinations of numbers from min to max

(min as number, max as number)=>
let 
    nums = {min..max},
    x = List.Generate(
        ()=>[a={nums{0},nums{1}}, idx=0],
        each [idx] < List.Count(nums)-1,
        each [a={nums{0}, nums{[idx]+2}}, idx=[idx]+1],
        each [a]
    ),
    result = if (min+1)=max then x else List.Combine({x,fnCombo(min+1,max)})
 in 
    result
```

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Customer Order", type text}, {"Item Type", type text}}),

//group by customer
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Customer Order"}, {
        {"Attributes", each List.Distinct([Item Type]), type list}
        }),

    //Create separate columns for each comparison
    similarities= 
      let 
        customers=#"Grouped Rows"[Customer Order],
        attrib = #"Grouped Rows"[Attributes],
        indices = fnCombo(0,List.Count(customers)-1),

        //calculate Jaccard/Tanimoto Coefficient
        tanimotos = 
            List.Generate(
                ()=>[x=
                    let 
                        Nc= List.Count(List.Intersect({attrib{indices{0}{0}},attrib{indices{0}{1}}})),
                        Na= List.Count(attrib{indices{0}{0}}),
                        Nb= List.Count(attrib{indices{0}{1}})
                    in Nc/(Na+Nb-Nc), idx=0],
                each [idx]<List.Count(indices),
                each [x=
                    let 
                        Nc= List.Count(List.Intersect({attrib{indices{[idx]+1}{0}},attrib{indices{[idx]+1}{1}}})),
                        Na= List.Count(attrib{indices{[idx]+1}{0}}),
                        Nb= List.Count(attrib{indices{[idx]+1}{1}})
                    in Nc/(Na+Nb-Nc), idx=[idx]+1],
                each [x]),
        
        //calculate matching list of customers being compared
        compares = List.Generate(
            ()=>[x=customers{indices{0}{0}} & " - " & customers{indices{0}{1}}, idx=0],
            each [idx]<List.Count(indices),
            each [x=customers{indices{[idx]+1}{0}} & " - " & customers{indices{[idx]+1}{1}}, idx=[idx]+1],
            each [x]
        )           
        in 
            {compares} & {tanimotos},

    //combine the two lists into a new table for output
    results = Table.FromColumns(
        similarities,
        type table[Customer Pairs=text, Similarity=number])

    in results
```

***Data***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Ron Sir, when you share solutions on Power Query, please if possible share the workbook in the answers as well, it helps me to follow the solution and learn from it!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Just enter the data and the code as posted in the question or the answer into your own workbook.

Comment: Thank You Sir, because it really helps me to learn from the solutions you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data by Item Type first. Assumes data is sheet named Sheet1 in columns A and B.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub analyse()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim dict As Object, ar, item As String, cust As String
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, r As Long, pc As Single
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 2 To lastrow
           cust = Trim(.Cells(r, 1))
           item = Trim(.Cells(r, 2))
           
           ' increment count for customer
           dict(cust) = dict(cust) + 1
           
           ' if next line another item create report
           If .Cells(r + 1, 2) <> item Then
                n = Sheets.Count
                Set ws = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(n))
                ws.Name = item
                ar = dict.keys
                ' columns
                For x = 0 To UBound(ar)
                    ' row 1 namee
                    ws.Cells(1, x + 2) = ar(x)
                    ' rows
                    For y = 0 To UBound(ar)
                        ' avoid comparing with self
                        If y <> x Then
                            ' percent of total
                            pc = dict(ar(x)) / (dict(ar(x)) + dict(ar(y)))
                            ws.Cells(x + 2, y + 2) = Format(pc, "0%")
                        End If
                        ' column 1 names
                        If y = 0 Then
                           ws.Cells(x + 2, 1) = ar(x)
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
                dict.RemoveAll
                i = i + 1
            End If
       Next
   End With
   MsgBox i & " items analysed", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")

End Sub
```